# Complex Analysis - Bruce P . Palka - Ex: 4.12

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me with this question. I tried to prove the HINT. But I have no idea how to solve this.

Question :

Knowing that  $ Re(z)>0 $ , demonstrate that $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|\geqslant 1$, with equality holding only when z is a real number in the interval $(0,1]$. ( Hint : First check that $Re(\bar{z}\sqrt{z^2-1})\geqslant 0$ for every $z$ under consideration.

I proved that $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|^2\geqslant 1+Re(\bar{z}\sqrt{z^2-1})$ . But I can not prove the HINT.

Comment: What branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is used?

Comment: This is the exact question from the book. So I had the same question too.

Comment: The product of the two branches is $1$. This means that your inequality is true for one of the branches and false for the other.

Comment: There are two 'standard' branches for $z \mapsto \sqrt{z^2-1}$: One with branch cut $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$ and another $[-1,1]$.  In either case, there needs to be more restrictions than just $\operatorname{re} z >0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's show $\text {Re}\,\bar z (z^2-1)^{1/2}\ge 0,$ where throughout I use the principal branches of $\arg z, z^{1/2}.$ This is obviously true if $z=1,$ so below I'll assume $z\ne 1.$

Fact: If $0 \le \arg w < \pi,$ then $\arg (w-1) \ge \arg w.$ Hopefully that's clear from the geometry. Suppose now $\text {Re}\, z > 0$ and $0\le\arg z < \pi/2.$ Then $\arg z^2 = 2 \arg z.$ Thus $\arg (z^2-1) \ge \arg z^2 = 2\arg z.$ Taking square roots gives $\arg (z^2-1)^{1/2} \ge \arg z.$ Since $\arg \bar z = -\arg z,$ we have $\arg \bar z (z^2-1)^{1/2}\ge 0,$ hence $\text {Re}\,\bar z (z^2-1)^{1/2}\ge 0.$ That takes care of the first quadrant; the proof for the fouth quadrant is similar.