# Show that if $Re{\{z}\}>0$ then $|z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}|\geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In [Complex Analysis - Bruce P . Palka - Ex: 4.12](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481748/672548) I have not been able to prove that $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|^2\geq 1+ Re{\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2-1}}\},$ what I get is:

$|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}|^2=(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})\overline{(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})}= (z+\sqrt{z^2-1})(\overline{z}+\overline{\sqrt{z^2-1}})=|z|^2+2 Re{\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2-1}}\}+|\sqrt{z^2-1}|^2 $

On the other hand, since $z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is a root of the polynomial $t^2-2zt+1$ then:

$1=|t(2z-t)|=|(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})(2z-z-\sqrt{z^2-1})|\leq |z|^2+2 |Im{\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2-1}}\}|+|\sqrt{z^2-1}|^2.$

But I can not get past here, can someone help me please.

Comment: The question's title and body don't match. Pleas check what exactly what you are really asking. And most of the times, these kind of questions use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Let $z = x+iy$, I think you can take it from here.

Comment: $|a+b|^2 = |a|^2+ 2 \operatorname{re} \bar{a} b + |b|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $w = re^{i\theta}$ is a complex number. Then $|\sqrt{w}|^2 = |r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}|^2 = r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}r^{1/2}e^{-i\theta/2} = r = |w|$. Now \begin{align*}
|z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}|^2  &= |z|^2 + 2\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\} + \left|\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right|^2\\ &= |z|^2 + 2\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\} + |z^2 -1|\\
&= |z^2| + 2\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\} + |z^2 -1|\\
&\geq|z^2 - (z^2 - 1)| + 2\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\}\\
&= 1 + 2\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Then it just remains to prove $\mathfrak{R}\left\{\overline{z}\sqrt{z^2 - 1}\right\} \geq 0$.

Comment: Please show how Re(conj(z)*√(z*z-1)) ≥ 0

Comment: @albert chan see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481748/complex-analysis-bruce-p-palka-ex-4-12